# Spatial (2D) sound in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, browser

For the needs of my game I need to have 2D sound. That means, the emmiter should be positioned somewhere on a 2D plane. How do I achieve this effect in Javascript? Do I need to use a special sound format or can I control the volume on the speakers?

I think I can get to the point where I have 2 volumes for each speaker, but I am clueless as how to apply different volumes for the same sound in Javascript.

Comment: A `<canvas>` game? Where's the sound coming from? An `<audio>` element?

Comment: Read this: [Web Audio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An article describing exactly this **including a demo** can be found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/games/#toc-3d).

To prevent link rot I will be quoting the most relevant parts below

> Luckily, Web Audio API comes with built-in hardware accelerated positional audio features that are quite straight forward to use.

The core idea is demonstrated in the code below:

```
PositionSample.prototype.changePosition = function(position) {
  // Position coordinates are in normalized canvas coordinates
  // with -0.5 < x, y < 0.5
  if (position) {
    if (!this.isPlaying) {
      this.play();
    }
    var mul = 2;
    var x = position.x / this.size.width;
    var y = -position.y / this.size.height;
    this.panner.setPosition(x * mul, y * mul, -0.5);
  } else {
    this.stop();
  }
};
```

The full source code of the working demo in the first link above can be found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/games/samples/position/position.js).

<sub>*Offtopic: I considered rewriting the quoted article by hand as a custom answer here, but that seemed relatively pointless as the article is already more than clear enough and doing double work seems pointless*</sub>

---

Compatibility wise, only a combination of flash and the previously mentioned code gives a true cross-browser positioning/panning audio solution (as flash is not available on certain mobile devices). Ideally I would advise against use of the audio API if this can be circumvented as it's not unlikely that things will change in the specification, thus possibly breaking your code (+ it's not unlikely for this not to work either way on mobile devices). The only scenario where using the more advanced web audio api's makes sense is if you are expecting to work at least another 6 to 18 months on your game (as that's the likely time it will take for the implementations to even stabalize to a usable point).

Comment: I don't care about compatibility, although I would like my code not to contain any Flash.

Comment: Haha, in that case the above solution is just perfect for you yeah :D (I guess that means you are only doing it to learn from, which is great :D )

Comment: Man, you're really trying to sell your "solution". It's just +50pts, take it easy. Relax.

Answer (score 2):

We've used SoundManager2 at work, at it was a really easy turn-key solutions and well documented API.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Example:

```
soundManager.createSound({
 id:'mySound1',
 url:'../mpc/audio/CHINA_1.mp3'
});
soundManager.play('mySound1');
```

BSD License: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/license.txt

Comment: For sound pan, you can record just the left or right channel and fade between the two. Any sound editor will allow that. It requires two files, but it's a solution.

Comment: Doesnt fading between 2 files require exact timing matching, which is sometimes not easily done?

Comment: The web audio API does have quite a number of useful tools for that, although you of course can't use the soundmanager library for any serious stuff like that. (See the article in my answer and scroll up  a bit for some timing explanations)

Comment: @david-mulder both JavaScript APIs are just libraries leveraging off of the more advanced HTML5 audio capabilities. But not all users (even now) are using HTML5 ready browsers. There is a place for both APIs, and soundmanager also handles non-HTML5 ready browsers as a fallback. If people already have the latest and greatest installed, then just use a Flash audio API and don't worry about HTML sound. The question was about sound in JavaScript and not just in HTML5.

Comment: Yeah, I have used the soundManager various times (e.g. for an extensive music player) so I know what I am talking about when I say that it's totally worthless if you are need game sound control. Exactly because it's trying to create cross browser compability it gives up **a lot** of control. (As I said, look at the article I referenced in my answer to see what's possible). And the question was about sound **for a html5 game** in **javascript** (not about a backwards compatible primarily flash solution for **music** playback).

Comment: Seriously, the only thing I pointed out in my previous comments in response to wizzard0 that he was right concercning these difficulties and that it was possible using newer API's, but not with your answer... I wasn't trying to sell my answer like you accused me off.

Comment: Sorry for the accusation, that came off too harsh. There is no mention of HTML5 in the question. The question was 2D sound in JavaScript and a solution to implement. We both presented a solution. May the best answer win.

Comment: Hmm, if you're going to make a game with javascript nowadays you would need to be a fool not to use some html5 techniques :P And this definitely wasn't a question on that (a fools) level. And I checked his profile back then to see his other answers which showed me he had made quite an impressive HTML5 game already. Oh well, sorry for getting so agitated over that accusation :) .